# How to use image from url in UICollectionView ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nsarray, uicollectionview

My code is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
   collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 20, 260, 270) collectionViewLayout:layout];
   [collectionView setDataSource:self];
   [collectionView setDelegate:self];

   [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
   [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

   [self.view addSubview:collectionView];

   string1=[NSString stringWithFormat:url];
   NSURL *jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
   UIImage *image1 =[[UIImage imageWithData:data]autorelease];
   set=[NSArray arrayWithObject:image1];
   tmp= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i=1; i<[set count]; i++)
        {
            [tmp addObject:[set objectAtIndex:i+1]];
        }


 }
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tmp count];
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[tmp objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]]] ;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```

and I feel that this action does not work or when I hurt things

```
cell.backgroundview =[UIImageView alloc]initwithimage:[UIImage imageNamed:[tmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Comment: You need to actually ask a question. What is it that isn't working? What do you want it to do?

Comment: @Fogmeister this action does not working. cell.backgroundview =[UIImageView alloc]initwithimage:[UIImage imageNamed:[tmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

Answer (score 0):

You do something wrong in your `viewDidLoad`

The only thing you need is to set a color to your UICollectionView so change your code like this for example :

```
[collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Assuming your array `tmp` is an array of image name (like "myImage.png") and and reload your collection view before the end of your `viewDidLoad` ;

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for you try like that:

```
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameImage.jpg"]];
```

Comment: My problem in this action:cell.backgroundview =[UIImageView alloc]initwithimage:[UIImage imageNamed:[tmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]; and some log displayed bellow : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: your array is empty so

Comment: yes if this is the log is because the array is empty, view you initialize the array?

Comment: did you fix you problem?